# mysql select with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is simple:

```
SELECT visibility_wall_post
FROM wall_post
WHERE id_wall_post = (
  SELECT MAX(id_wall_post)
  FROM wall_post
  WHERE id_user = :id_user
)
```

I want to select `visibility_wall_post` if `visibility_wall_post_shared` is `NULL`.
If `visibility_wall_post_shared` is not `NULL` I want to select `visibility_wall_post`.

Comment: Don't update this to  a totally different question. Press the "Ask Question" button and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function in MySQL.

Use it like:

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(visibility_wall_post, visibility_wall_post_shared)
FROM wall_post
WHERE id_wall_post = (
  SELECT MAX(id_wall_post)
  FROM wall_post
  WHERE id_user = :id_user
)
```

You then just have to make sure only one of the two columns can be NULL.